# How to display a nested array in Next.js or to change it to object

Tags: javascript, arrays, postgresql, next.js

```
{
    "count": 2,
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": "5ab46e31-391c-46a7-8e45-db9ada07626d",
            "name": "admin",
            "email": "admin@gmail.com",
            "phoneNumber": "95397454542325",
            "username": "admin",
            "password": "$2b$10$esLfedWAPEMAgWJ5HBAFQu6u47Cbfep7hnUTDZPswb4gWFhZW0rbm",
            "role": "admin",
            "isActive": true,
            "createdAt": "2023-09-29T11:00:55.388Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-09-29T11:00:55.388Z"
        },
        {
            "id": "58aacbcd-2344-40f1-a9e9-11c70d44cbb4",
            "name": "Aman",
            "email": "aman2000@gmail.com",
            "phoneNumber": "8304893218",
            "username": "Aman-admin",
            "password": "$2b$10$uZZrRz5bATzJ3jPCAURpKeEP/TaHhoWhmKUvWSyIrOvKMmD3yNuKi",
            "role": "user",
            "isActive": true,
            "createdAt": "2023-10-07T09:58:51.193Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-10-07T10:00:31.590Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

The above is the JSON data to be displayed

```
'use client'
import React from 'react';
const plans = async () => {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/plans', { cache: 'no-store' }); // fetch gives a promise, so use const res = await
  console.log(res);//table table-zebra absolute top-24 left-40

  const users = await res.json();

  return (
    <div>
      <button className='bg-sky-600 text-black p-2 rounded-lg absolute top-4 right-40 hover:text-white transition-colors'>Create plans</button>
      <h1 className='absolute top-14 left-40'>Plans</h1>
      <div>
        <table className='table-column-group absolute top-24 left-40 min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-200 border'> 
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {users.map((data) => (
              <tr key={data.id}>
                <td>{data.name}</td>
                <td>{data.email}</td>
              </tr>your text
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default plans;
```

This is the front-end code in Next.js
As its nested array its not displayed i think. Maybe if changed to object. The normal arrays are displayed perfectly fine. Just this. What changes should be made in Next.js to display it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see you are getting a response from your API that consists of two keys `count` and `rows`, and you want to render the items within the `rows` key so replace the `users.map()` with `users.rows.map()`;

**Example**

```
'use client'
import React from 'react';
const plans = async () => {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/plans', { cache: 'no-store' }); // fetch gives a promise, so use const res = await
  console.log(res);//table table-zebra absolute top-24 left-40

  const users = await res.json();

  return (
    <div>
      <button className='bg-sky-600 text-black p-2 rounded-lg absolute top-4 right-40 hover:text-white transition-colors'>Create plans</button>
      <h1 className='absolute top-14 left-40'>Plans</h1>
      <div>
        <table className='table-column-group absolute top-24 left-40 min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-200 border'> 
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {users.rows.map((data) => (
              <tr key={data.id}>
                <td>{data.name}</td>
                <td>{data.email}</td>
              </tr>your text
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default plans;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works now. But can I call the data...say data.name into another page ? What changes should I make in order to do that.

Comment: you can pass the data in props onto other components. but if you want to make the users global and easy to access everywhere use context API.